# How to choose a necessary android report layout

Tags: android, android-layout, report

I am a beginner in android programing
I'm a little confused about choosing layouts for my report because there are so many layouts like `GridView`, `GridLayout`, `TableLayout`and etc.
Because of my basic web I think make a report like in web use table to display data array like datagrid

My expect report look like this:

[image: Report that I want]

I use `GridView` but it is not as expected.
Thanks for any help.

---

my current coding and result

[image: PHP result]

```
public class fragment_result_listab extends Fragment {
View list_ab_result;
String selectresult_ab;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    list_ab_result= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result_listab,container,false);

    GridView gv = (GridView) list_ab_result.findViewById(R.id.listab);
     //value from other fragment (result from php)
    selectresult_ab = getArguments().getString("trans_value");


    String[] nselectresult=selectresult_ab.split(",");

    List<String> resultlist=null;


    resultlist = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < nselectresult.length; i++) {
        resultlist.add(resultlist.size(),nselectresult[i]);

    }

    final ArrayAdapter<String> gridViewArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.cell_gridview, resultlist);
    gv.setAdapter(gridViewArrayAdapter);


    return list_ab_result;

}
```

}

fragment_result_listab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mybg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity ="center"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewlistab"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,UselessParent">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/listab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="4"
                tools:ignore="NestedScrolling">
            </GridView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

cell_gridview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/mybgwhite"
        android:lines="5"
        android:maxLines="5"
       android:padding="5dp"/>
```

current report

[image: Current Result]

Comment: "but it is not as expected."  What did you expect?  What did you get?  What code are you using?  Without those things, we can't answer.   (For the record, GridView isn't likely what you need, it doesn't do what a web programmer would expect.  You likely want ListView or RecyclerView)

Comment: code added java and xml

Answer (score 0):

Problem solving, I use listview for the desired report

https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html#

http://jsonformatter.onlinewebtoolz.com/